# Who will get the bounty amount?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Bounty faq says that if owner of bounty does not give bounty to any answer in 7 days half of bounty amount will be given to highest voted answer. But what if two answers have same number of vote and that are the highest votes among answers. ***Who will get the half amount of bounty?***

Answer (score 5):

My *understanding* is that the **earliest** *eligible* answer will get it; where eligible means "posted after the bounty was placed" and "with at least 2 votes"

Comment: so if i answered a question and get 2 up votes. after that person starts bounty on question and you answer the question and get 2 up votes. So at the end you will be rewarded. Is this what you wanna say?

Comment: @Harry - If you answered the question before the bounty starts then you are not eligible for the auto awarded bounty. Only answers posted *after* the bounty has started are eligible for the auto awarded bounty. Any answer, regardless of whether they posted before or after the bounty had started, are eligible for the bounty so long as it is awarded by the owner of the bounty.

Comment: @Barry: so if no one answers after bounty is started then the persons who have answered the question before the bounty started will not get any reward even if they have more than 2 up votes. is this right?

Comment: @Harry - Yes that is correct. This only applies if the bounty owner does not award the bounty. If the bounty is left to auto award then in the scenario you describe no one will receive the bounty.

Comment: @Barry: is this same if person who have answered before the bounty started gets more than 2 up votes after bounty is started ?

Comment: @Harry - Yes it is, because the answer was posted before the bounty was started.

Comment: @Barry, @Marc: don't you think its not fair. If person gets 2 up votes after bounty starts he should be rewarded. What you think?

Comment: @Harry - If the bounty was started after the person answered the question then I guess the assumption is that the persons answer does not resolve the OP issue otherwise a bounty wouldn't have been started. If it really is the right answer, say after an edit, the bounty owner should manually award the bounty.