# Should I accept an helpful answer even if no answer truly answered the question

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer should I accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80788/which-answer-should-i-accept)

I have asked this question: [Why is my AsOrdered PLINQ query faster than my unordered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906698/why-is-my-asordered-plinq-query-faster-than-my-unordered-one) and got two very good answers.

They gave me leads to investigate I hadn't though about, and since one of them (plus another person in the comment) reproduced my code without seeing the effect I observed, I am lead to believe that it may be due to a difference in hardware.

Something that people can very difficultly diagnose from a distance.

The main thing however is that I do not have any certain answer to my initial question: ***"Why is my ordered plinq query faster than the unordered one?"***.

What should I do? Not accept an answer since I don't have a definitive answer and that the posters didn't explicitly say in their answer text : "barring all my other suggestions it is probably an hardware or implementation problem".

Or should I give the accepted answer to the person who most helped me trying to find an explanation for something they possibly can't pinpoint for certain without access to my machine.

There is also the possibility that there is an answer that someone could give me but no one has done so, but that doesn't seem so certain at this time.

This would seem like a good situation for a bounty except for my low reputation (at the time of this writing) and the fact that my question isn't related to work or a personal project (just me mucking around one night).

Comment: I had already read the question which is a supposed duplicate before posting, but I feel it isn't and it doesn't cover my exact situation, whether it is situation 1, 2 or 3 in said post. My two answers aren't identical. They don't form a complete answer on their own and I didn't get an answer in a comment. Would my question be ok if I rewrite it as: "should we accept helpful answer that don't solve the question if we feel we won't get any better answers?". Reading the suppose duplicate and it's accepted answer doesn't give me any guidance on my situation.

Comment: If the answers plus comments gave you enough hints to provide an actual answer, make the answer yourself and accept it. If your question really doesn't have an answer, leave it alone and ignore all the nay-sayers who come by later and tell you to work on your accept rate. Remember that SO is all about getting the best answer to a problem.